# Customizing UI elements in Eclipse default Java Editor via plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Eclipse that will allow me to modify various elements within the default java text editor. I've found lots of tutorials for creating my own text editor for a different language, but nothing for editing the default java editor. Specifically, I want to be able to run a command and highlight certain areas of the code based on a different program. How do I develop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement your own type of **markers** and maybe associate **annotations** with them. Then you can associate the java editor with the annotations to show them. Your application will generate the markers.

Specifically you might want to start to read about `org.eclipse.core.resources.marker` extension point and `IResource.createMarker()` to create the markers.

Answer (score 1):

Its doable. You need to find the right extension point that allows you to add functionality to the java editor.

See [IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecjdt/). The example with the heading "How do you analyze Java code to apply modifications" seems to be what you want to do.